# c3.js set onClick property in chart generated from another function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

My goal is to get 3 charts, with the most recently selected series in the first chart updating the second chart, and the most recently selected series in the second chart updating the third chart.

I start by setting up 3 divs:

```
<div id="chart1"></div>
<div id="chart2"></div>
<div id="chart3"></div>
```

I then generate 3 charts like so (essentially the same, but with different detail levels in the source data):

```
var chart1 = c3.generate({
    bindto: document.getElementById('chart1'),
    data: {
        x: 'date',
        url: 'file1.csv'
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%Y-%m-%d',
                count: 8
            },
            label: "Date"
        },
        y: {
            label: "Y Label"
        }
    },
    // irrelevant options removed
    legend: {
        item: {
            onclick: (id) => {
                chart1.toggle(id);
                chart_options2.data.url = 'file2_'+ id +'.csv';
                if(chart1.data.shown(id).length == 1 ){
                    generateChart2(id);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

var chart2 = c3.generate({
    bindto: document.getElementById('chart2'),
// etc.

var chart3 = c3.generate({
    bindto: document.getElementById('chart3'),
// etc.
```

The function `generateChart2()` will use the `id` of the selected series in chart1 to generate a new chart in the place of chart2. Likewise I have a similar function `generateChart3()` which will use the `id` of the selected series in chart2 to generate a new chart in the place of chart3. These functions look like this:

```
    function generateChart2(id) {
        c3.generate(chart_options2);
    };
```

With `chart_options` being identical to the original set up options, except for the updated file source (see `chart_options2.data.url = 'file2_'+ id +'.csv';` above).

Initially, these all seem to work ok. The problem arises when a new chart2 is created using the `generateChart2()` function, and the `onclick` property no longer seems to work for certain things. Testing with `console.log`, the `onclick` still seems to be called, and I can update the chart options var, but I can't use any of the other commands:

```
                onclick: function (id) {
                    console.log('test'); // returns 'test'
                    chart2.toggle(id); // doesn't work
                    chart_options3.data.url = 'file3_'+ id +'.csv'; // works
                    if(chart2.data.shown(id).length == 1 ){
                        generateChart3(id); // doesn't work
                    }
```

I *suspect* it has something to do with the namespace, or how I'm using the chart names, or how I'm calling the function. I've spent a couple of days looking at this problem, but all my research hasn't really made it much clearer which direction I should be looking in.

**EDIT:** I found a workaround, which makes sense for my use case, but doesn't help me learn what I was doing wrong. Now instead of reusing `c3.generate` to dynamically create a new chart every time a series is selected in the previous chart, I am using `unload()` and `load()`. This seems to be working well, but I would very much appreciate an explanation or clarification of what I was doing wrong the first time. Updated code:

```
            onclick: function (id) {
                chart1.toggle(id);
                if(chart1.data.shown(id).length == 1 ){
                    chart2.unload();
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        chart2.load({
                            url: 'file2_'+ id +'.csv'
                        });
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
```